# Full iMDB page download

Tags: download, autoit, imdb

I'm trying to download webpages like: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6238614/episodes/?year=2017. Using `InetRead()`:

```
$sim01 = BinaryToString(InetRead('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6238614/episodes/?year=2017', 1),4)    ; force reload, UTF
```

Or custom function:

```
Func _HTTP_Download($URL)
   $oHTTP = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
   $oHTTP.Open("GET", $URL)
   $oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/117.0")
   $oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en")
   $oHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
   $oHTTP.Send()
   return $oHTTP.ResponseText
EndFunc
```

It doesn't show all episodes at once. You have to manually click "50 more" or "All" buttons below the list. How to load entire page at once using AutoIt, a .dll file, cURL or Wget?